# How can I get all content between two pipes using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a String say

String s = "|India| vs Aus";

In this case result should be only **India**.

Second case :

String s = "Aus vs |India|";
In this case result should be only **India**.

3rd case:

String s = "|India| vs |Aus|"
Result shouls contain only **India, Aus**. vs should not present in output.

And in these scenarios, there can be any other word in place of vs. e.g. String can be like this also |India| in |Aus|. and the String can be like this also |India| and |Sri Lanka| in |Aus|. I want those words that are present in between two pipes like India, Sri Lanka , Aus.

I want to do it in Java.

Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at something similar to this:

```
    String s = "|India| vs |Aus|";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|(.*?)\\|");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

You need to use the group to get the contents inside the paranthesis in the regexp.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I am happy to help! Please accept the answer if you feel it is the right one.

Comment: I have one more query. Is there any way to find how many words i will get in output. Like in above case there will be two words.

Comment: Just add a counter inside the while loop. `i++`.

Answer (score 6):

You would use a regex like...

```
\|[^|]+\|
```

...or...

```
\|.+?\|
```

You must escape the pipe because the pipe has special meaning in a regex as *or*.

Comment: Its not giving the desired response

Comment: @Vishal the regex from @alex is correct (+1), if you are not getting the desired result you should show the Java code you are using.

Comment: Sorry, This is working. I did some mistake. Thanks for helping.