# Regular expression, match substring between asterisks and pipes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find strings that are surrounded by asterisks and pipelines, for example: `*|FOO|*`, `*|BAAAAAR|*`
I already researched several other answers, but every time I combine asterisks with pipelines, it does not work. Can anyone help me?

And I need to find all the possibilities in a same text, for example:

```
Hello *|FOO|*, let's play with *|BAAAAAR|*
```

I need to find both `'*|FOO|*'` and `'*|BAAAAAR|*'`.

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: I try using these codes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646448/how-can-i-get-all-content-between-two-pipes-using-regular-expression

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123502/regular-expression-match-substring-between-pipes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753090/regex-to-match-string-between-asterisk-with-line-breaks

Just to be clear: i suck at regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.findall`. Since `*` and `|` are special characters in regex, you must escape that in-order to match literal `*`, `|` characters.

```
>>> s = "Hello *|FOO|*, let's play with *|BAAAAAR|*"
>>> re.findall(r'\*\|.*?\|\*', s)
['*|FOO|*', '*|BAAAAAR|*']
```

Comment: I just saw your correction Raj. It seems to be working. In 5 minutes I will accept your answer